# How can I set an "if" statement in Wordpress where it checks for a custom subfield and if it exists then execute a shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to set up my php so it checks for if the `'contact_form_module'` field is being used and then if it has that field then I'd like it to drop the shortcode stored in the sub field `'form_shortcode.'` I think I'm messing up the syntax to check for the field or subfield?

I either want it to drop in the text field as part of the `echo do_shortcode` code, or I want it to execute a pre-determined shortcode as long as the subfield is being used.

In my php file I have:

```
<!-- Start Content Sections -->
<?php if (have_rows('content_section')) : ?>
    <?php while (have_rows('content_section')) : the_row();?>
        <?php
        $content_section_type = get_row_layout();

        switch ($content_section_type) {
            case 'full_width_content_module':
            $content_section_type = 'full-width-content-module';
            break;
            case 'full_width_content_module_left_border':
            $content_section_type = 'full-width-content-module-left-border';
            break;
            
            case 'contact_form_module':
            $content_section_type = 'contact-form-module';
            break;
            default:
            $content_section_type = '';
            break;
        }
        ?>
        <?php if ($content_section_type) : ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'partials/content-section', $content_section_type ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- End Content Sections -->
```

I've tried a few methods but nothing seems to work. Appreciate any help.

This is one thing I tried:

```
<?php if ($content_section_type) : ?>
        <?php if(get_sub_field('form_shortcode')) {
<? php echo do_shortcode("[contact-form-7 id="3348" title="Contact Us Form"]"); ?>
} ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```